# ifPresent return something orElse

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type

I need some help with the below code snippet.. `raiseWorkQueueTask` should return the notification if it can find any `null != previousPeriod.getOldId()` and the `outcomeCode` of the `riseWorkQueue` is "L3".... but I get an error at

```
*.ifPresent(()->proceedWorkQueue(ip)).orElse(null);*
```

I get an error saying `"Cannot infer functional interface"` .. I also tried other variations ...

```
.ifPresent(()->proceedWorkQueue(ip).orElse(null));
.ifPresent(proceedWorkQueue(ip).orElse(null));
```

---

```
private Optional<Notification> riseWorkQueueTask(IP ip) {
    return ip.getPreviousPeriods().stream()
              .filter(previousPeriod -> null != previousPeriod.getOldId())
              .findAny()
              .ifPresent(() -> proceedWorkQueue(ip))
              .orElse(null);
}

private Optional<Notification> proceedWorkQueue(Ip ip) {
    EntryParametersDTO entryParametersDTO = new EntryParametersDTO();
    Insurance insurance = ip.getInsurance();
    //.....
    return queueClient.riseWorkQueue(entryParametersDTO)
              .filter(w -> w.getStateDTO() != null)
              .filter(w -> StateConstants.L3.equalsIgnoreCase(
                              w.getStateDTO().getOutcomeCode()))
              .flatMap(flag -> retrieveNotificationFromDB(insurance));
}
```

Comment: Are `IP` and `Ip` two different classes/types? Very confusing. Or is it a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You're possibly looking out for `map` as:

```
private Optional<Notification> riseWorkQueueTask(IP ip) {
    return ip.getPreviousPeriods().stream()
            .filter(previousPeriod -> null != previousPeriod.getOldId())
            .findAny()
            .map(i -> proceedWorkQueue(i).orElse(null)); 
    // orElse if 'proceedWorkQueue' returns empty Optional
}
```

or rather simply using `flatMap` as:

```
private Optional<Notification> riseWorkQueueTask(IP ip) {
    return ip.getPreviousPeriods().stream()
            .filter(previousPeriod -> null != previousPeriod.getOldId())
            .findAny()
            .flatMap(i -> proceedWorkQueue(i));
}
```

Comment: Note: If you were intending to return `null` instead for an `Optional<Notification>`, it would be an abuse of Optional rather.

Comment: If I have understood the problem just approximately right, the second snippet is right. Perhaps `.flatMap(p -> proceedWorkQueue(ip))` in the last line to use the `ip` passed into the method.

Answer (score 0):

`ifPresent` is a void method which is meant to process the ultimate value of the optional. But the error you're getting is due to the fact that you're passing a lambda that doesn't match the signature of the expected functional interface. It should be:

```
//the lambda must take 1 parameter, even if you don't use it
.ifPresent(period -> proceedWorkQueue(ip))
```

If you need to just run `proceedWorkQueue(ip)` if the optional has a value, you can either call `map` (kind of cheating):

```
return ip.getPreviousPeriods().stream()
        .filter(previousPeriod -> null != previousPeriod.getOldId())
        .findAny()
        .map(period ->{proceedWorkQueue(ip); return period;});
```

Or write it in a readable way by using an `if` block:

```
Optional<Notification> value = ip.getPreviousPeriods().stream()
        .filter(previousPeriod -> null != previousPeriod.getOldId())
        .findAny();

if(value.isPresent()) {
    proceedWorkQueue(ip);
}

return value;
```

Comment: I am not very sure, but the question probably intends( section `.ifPresent(() -> proceedWorkQueue(ip))`) that if after `filter` any such IP is present, `map` it to the other method response. Also the return of `null` for the signature `Optional<T>` doesn't really makes sense.

Comment: @nullpointer That's a good observation about the null return value. Will fix that. But I'm not very clear on what the intent is, so this is more about the compilation error. Thanks!